# Shnayim Mikre during Krias HaTorah

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, tzibur-community, shnayim-mikra

May one read "Shnayim Mikre V'Echad Targum" during the leining of Krias HaTorah on Shabbos morning?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1210/759

Answer (score 4):

The Mechaber rules in [Hilchos Shnayim Mikrah (286:5)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%94) that one is permitted to recite shnayim mikra during krias hatorah. Although one may not learn during kriyas hatorah, shnayim mikra is different because it the same thing that is being read. The Pri Megadim writes that one must do so quitely in order not to disturb others. In [Hichos Kriyas Hatorah (146:2)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%95) the Mechaber adds that when the kriah is de'oraysa such as Parshas Zachor one must listen to the reader. He also writes that it is fitting for one who is scrupulous to always listen to the Baal Koreh. The [Mishna Berurah](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%95) (146:15) quotes several poskim (Pri Chadash, Magen Avraham in name of Sh"la, Gr"a) who maintain that it is forbidden according to halacha. However the Mishna Berura notes that between aliyos even this opinion would permit it.

Comment: I've heard that it's only allowed if you read along posuk by posuk according to the custom of repeating the entire parsha at once, as opposed to the more common practice of repeating each posuk.