# Are hefseks in between aliyot in krias hatorah made by the Rabbi issur?

Tags: synagogue, torah-reading, hefsek-interruption

In a lot of Chabad shuls I noticed the Rabbi usually gives a small drasha in between aliyot explaining what's coming up next or even have games for kids asking them for example to find how many alephs are in the coming aliyot.

Is this permitted ?

[image: Rav Moshe Feinstein answer כא that this is completely issur]
Rav Moshe Feinstein כא is pretty clear its issur.
Any opinion that permits this ??? 
Thankyou

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/talking-during-torah-reading

Comment: I'm looking specifically regarding a rabbi.  Not bein gavra lgavra which I see is permitted by some even so far as idle talk.

Comment: Re your last comment. It is puzzling that sometimes, a seemingly endless sequence of *Mi Sheberach* which is not just for the oleh but for his relatives and his friends is allowed and justified for the sake of getting monetary donations for the shul. Besides being a *torach tzibbur*, it encourages talking and it's unnecessary. But, it seems permitted. I'd rather have a rav give a drasha that people listen to. Why should that, in contrast, be forbidden?

Comment: I just realized that Chaba"d doesn't need to ask for donations during Torah reading or tefillah. So much for their following R. Feinstein's opinion, though. There's nothing written by The Rebbe regarding this?

Comment: I was also wondering about the misheberachs and the asking of donations or putting the aliyot up for auctions in other orthodox shuls. I showed this to chabad rabbis and they couldn't really direct me further than to say we dont always follow R.Feinstein.